# Is the reciprocal of an algebraic integer also an algebraic integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> In class I have seen the following argumentation as part of the lemma that $\alpha \in \mathfrak{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)}$, i.e. $\alpha$ comes from the ring of integers of a cyclotomic field, is a unit if and only if $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$:
>
> Since $N(\alpha)N(\alpha^{-1}) = 1$ and $N(\alpha), N(\alpha^{-1}) \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$.

I know that $\mathfrak{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)} = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and thus $N(\alpha)\in \mathbb{Z}$, but I do not get why $N(\alpha^{-1}) \in \mathbb{Z}$ should hold. Is it because $\alpha^{-1}$ is also an algebraic integer?

Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Doesn't your assumption that $\alpha$ is a unit, mean that it is a unit  in the relevant ring of integers and hence $\alpha^{-1}$ is in the same ring of integers?

Comment: @Rob Arthan: I think you are right, I got confused with the wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, then $\alpha^{-1}$ is not necessarily an algebraic integer (e.g. 1/2 is not an algebraic integer).

However, in this case, we are assuming $\alpha$ is a unit (we are trying to prove that $\alpha$ is a unit implies $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$) which means by definition that $\alpha^{-1}$ is an algebraic integer.